# How to replace rotten window frame?

Tags: windows

We have a window that is in a shower. I had noticed the paint was pealing on the outside of the house and realized that the caulk between the tile and window was gone, letting water drip down and to the outside. I fixed that issue. When I took off the framing on the outside, the wood is all rotten and soggy. I figure that I need to clean out the rotten wood and then rip new pieces of wood to replace the damage wood.The window opening is too big for the window, so they have the double trim. The left weeping hole is also half covered by the window flashing, which seems to be not correct. I fixed the issue inside, so what else do I need to do to fix the outside issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this a replacement window, or is it original to the house? Does the widow jamb fill the whole wall thickness or is there a jamb extension to finish the window depth to the inside finish wall. A picture would help here. If there is a jamb extension to the inside, most certainly the sill is not the only thing rotted.

Comment: The window is not original to the house. The jamb does fill the whole wall too.